# awk sum of consecutive rows at specific columns

Tags: awk

```
chr1    3000035 +   0   0   CHG CTG
chr1    3000037 -   0   0   CHG CAG
chr1    3000045 +   0   0   CHG CAG
chr1    3000047 -   0   0   CHG CTG
chr1    3000048 +   0   0   CHG CTG
chr1    3000050 -   0   0   CHG CAG
```

Most of the data is like this: how to ignore this error.

I am quite new to `awk` and don't know how to do this.
For the data set `T-C.txt`:

```
chr1    3000035 +   0   0   CHG CTG
chr1    3000037 -   0   1   CHG CAG
chr1    3000045 +   0   0   CHG CAG
chr1    3000047 -   0   0   CHG CTG
chr1    3000048 +   3   0   CHG CTG
chr1    3000050 -   0   0   CHG CAG
chr1    3000109 +   0   0   CHG CAG
chr1    3000111 -   0   0   CHG CTG
```

the script:

```
less T-C.txt | awk '{sum=sum+$4+$5}  {if(sum>0) print;} (NR%2==0) {sum=0;}'
```

produces the output of:

```
chr1    3000037 -   0   1   CHG CAG
chr1    3000048 +   3   0   CHG CTG
chr1    3000050 -   0   0   CHG CAG
```

Although I also want the + strand records whether having both 0 because later on I have to use the value of only positive strands at 2nd column.

Example:

```
chr1    3000035 +   2   1   CHG CTG
chr1    3000037 -   0   3   CHG CAG
chr1    3000045 +   0   0   CHG CAG
chr1    3000047 -   0   1   CHG CTG
chr1    3000048 +   0   0   CHG CTG
chr1    3000050 +   0   0   CHG CTG
```

I have a file like the above and I am searching for some `awk` command that will add

```
[column4 of '+' strand + column5 of '+' strand + column4 of '-' strand + column5 of '-' strand]
```

That means every 2 lines if sum of them is more than 0 then print it on a text file otherwise don't print. But the alternate `+` and `-` that only have difference of 1 number like 3000035 and 3000037 should be maintained as these are considered to be only one record.
From above example, only the following records will be printed — not the last 2 rows:

```
chr1    3000035 +   2   1   CHG CTG
chr1    3000037 -   0   3   CHG CAG
chr1    3000045 +   0   0   CHG CAG
chr1    3000047 -   0   1   CHG CTG
```

After that I want to print sum to a new file in front of + strand value and calculate the  percentage like

```
[($4/$4+$5)*100 of '+'strand +($4/$4+$5)*100 of -strand]/2
```

and the result would be like:

```
chr1    3000035: sum= 6 percentage=['+strand'=66.66+'-strand'=0]/2=33.33%
chr1    3000035 6 33.33
```

This should only be printed to the file.
Please if any one knows `awk` commands, explain them to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should get you started towards your goal.

Put the following in a file, say script.awk

```
$ cat script.awk
NR % 2 == 0 && sum {
    sum += $4 + $5;
    avg = ($4 / ($4 + $5)) * 100;
    if (sum > 0) {
        print prev, sum, (avg + pavg) / 2
    }
}

NR % 2 {
    prev = $1 FS $2;
    sum = $4 + $5;
    if (sum == 0) {
        next;
    }
    pavg = ($4 / ($4 + $5)) * 100
}
```

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
chr1 3000035 6 33.3333
```

Comment: thanks alot.but it gave me firstly error in  $ cat script.awk thats a syntax error .So I removed that line from script.awk file and then it is giving me 
  fatal: division by zero attempted. If I have many records with this zeros then how to ignore this fatal error division by zero.

Comment: It would help if you can post some data for which this fails. The first line was to show the content of the script and is not part of the script.

Comment: chr1 3000035 + 0 0 CHG CTG
chr1 3000037 - 0 0 CHG CAG
chr1 3000045 + 0 0 CHG CAG
chr1 3000047 - 0 0 CHG CTG
chr1 3000048 + 0 0 CHG CTG
chr1 3000050 - 0 0 CHG CAG

Comment: i have entered the data lines from real file in original q.

Comment: also :the outfile file will be formed where or do i need to write like awk -f script.awk data.file > output.txt        actually i m very new to this thats y asking such q.How can i run it on 61 files of differnt names but all are in a single folder and i want the output file names same as that of input file names

Comment: if this fatal error cant be ignored then is it possible to remove the records means if + strand is giving fatal error then there is no use to take %age of its negative strand.